# How can I access dynamically added elements in views via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to access and modify elements that are loaded with angular views. I can't seem to do it, however the element is outputted in console just fine.

## Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <div data-ng-view=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/pxgradient/pxgradient-1.0.2.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/plugins/angularjs/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## View

```
<div class="home">
    <h1 class="gradient">Transformation is comming</h1>
</div>
```

## Javascript

```
$(function () {
    var element = $('.gradient');

    console.log(element); // this works

    element.css('color', 'red'); // this does not
});
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an element called "element". The reason you can `console.log(element)` is probably because element is some predefined object or the like.

Comment: your javascript code runs when angular app is not ready and not bootstrapped yet. So the `.gradient` element doesn't exist in that time. The reason why you see it in console, is because all console objects are evaluated when you are viewing them, not when they are logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I have a solution, try this:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $('.gradient').css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your element might not be "ready" yet (not in the DOM yet).

You need to access to it in jquery document.ready function
If you use Angular, after the bootstrapping process is done, use Angular angular.element(document).ready

Example code: http://pairp.com/6144/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your element has a css rule that you should override.
Try this:

```
$('.gradient').removeAttr('style').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need write CSS as object:

```
   element.css({'color':'red'});
```